# Routing conflict between HTML5 and angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm new to angularjs and fell in love as soon as i knew about the concept.
So I had this app where using html and css i created the look of a single page app where I had linking between different locations in page as seen on below quote.
Come angularjs and I used ngRoute. But now there's a conflict between angular and generic HTML as to where to redirect on link clicking.

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list" style="font-size:17px">
        <li class="nav-header">Demand Type</li>
        <li><a id="link-add" href="#add"><i class="icon-font"></i>&nbsp;ADD-14</a></li>
        <li><a id="link-cp" href="#cp"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i>&nbsp;Cash Purchase</a></li>
        <li><a id="link-search" href="#search"><i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;Search Demand</a></li>
    </ul>                   
</div>
```

Now the # earlier directed to specific parts of the same page and i used CSS tricks to bring that segment to the front.
After applying angular, this all i managed to bring in front using ngAnimate instead of CSS but there are segments inside locations, like for e.g. I click **add** it redirects to **add** but **add** itself has more links to redirect to like **add integer/float/string**, how do I deal with it?
Please help, i've considered ui-router n nested routing techniques but it would be a great relief if I could use my original CSS to redirect to bigger segment e.g.**add** and then implement angular routing within to redirect to **int/float/string**.
Thank You for being patient!

Comment: Check out ng-href, it might help [NG-HREF](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref)

Comment: nops..doesn't do it!!